# Excluding a Junit4 test dependency

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit5

I have a slightly legacy parent pom (which I cannot un-inherit) with the following snippet

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.12</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

My child project is a brand new project where I **want to use only Junit5**. However I think because of inheritance the maven surefire plugin 2.22 is running both Junit4 and Junit 5 tests when vintage is included and only runs Junit5 when no vintage artifact is present.

Intellij happily allows you to write both Junit4 (org.junit.Test) and Junit5 (org.jupiter.api.Test)

Is there any way to exclude Junit4 completely (even if one is in the parent)? For new projects it makes more sense  to simply write Junit 5 tests.

Failing this if there is any way to atleast hint the Intellij to not use Junit4 would be useful?

Comment: The first thing is you have a parent which defines dependencies it's doing it wrong ..only using dependencyManagement is ok..otherwise simply wrong...

Comment: _I cannot uninherit_ so you need to keep it as `<parent />` in the child's pom? Because changing it just as to be a "normal" dependency in the child's pom with exclusion for junit4 might help.